# Jenkins: question marks in msbuild warning/error messages

Tags: windows, jenkins, msbuild, console, output

I've configured a build for ASP.NET project. In pipeline, I use the following line for the build:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\build-develop\Solution.sln" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /clp:disableconsolecolor
```

Compilation goes fine, warning/error messages are replaced with question marks

```
warning CS0219: ?????????? "blnStringEncrypted" ????????? ????????, ?? ??? ?? ???? ?? ????????????.
```

How can I fix that to get useful messages?

Comment: This can happen when your windows UI language and console codepage don't match.. what is your UI language and output of `chcp`?

Comment: On my server Windows UI language is english. In its console `chcp` is  437, but the problem still occurs

Comment: And you're viewing the server's compiler output logs on your console? Or are you viewing them on the server's console? If the former, what is your computer's language and code page?

Comment: Well, I'm viewing the server's compiler output logs. This happens only to msbuild warning/error messages. Other output is fine